# Where are the signatures to callbacks such as this->client_->async_send_request( request, callback );

Tags: ros2, c++

Sorry if this is dumb question I am new to C++

In node member functions such as:

this->client_->async_send_request(request, callback);

Where are the signatures to the callback functions documented?

If I look at the API documentation at http://docs.ros.org/en/humble/p/rclcpp/generated/classrclcpp_1_1Client.html#classrclcpp_1_1Client

All I see is:

Parameters
:
request – [in] request to be send.

I can determine the signatures from the tutorials. However, I can't seem to find formal documentation. Am I missing something important?

cb – [in] callback that will be called when we get a response for this request.